# Download all linked files from Wikipedia page

Tags: bash, download, wget, wikipedia

I would like to use this `Wikipedia` page - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_members_of_the_United_States_House_of_Representatives

It contains several links to `.jpg` images, and I would like to download all of the images into a folder. I am on Mac.

I have tried using `wget` but so far have been unable.

EDIT: To clarify, I would like for a script to click on every link on the page, then download the page. This is because I need the page to be redirected first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `xmlstarlet` for this purpose:

```
xmlstarlet sel --net --html -t -m "//img" -v "@src" -n 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_members_of_the_United_States_House_of_Representatives'
```

will give you all the `src` fields of the `img` tags in the page at `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_members_of_the_United_States_House_of_Representatives`.

You'll notice that the output lines are missing a heading `http:`, so we'll have to add this.

Then:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    [[ $line = //* ]] && line="http:$line"
    wget "$line"
done < <(
    xmlstarlet sel --net --html -t -m "//img" -v "@src" -n 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_members_of_the_United_States_House_of_Representatives'
)
```

should retrieve the image files.

---

From your comment I now understand your requirement: you want to get all the `href` fields of the `a` nodes that contain an `img` node. An `xpath` that fulfills this requirement is:

```
//a[img]
```

Hence,

```
xmlstarlet sel --net --html -t -m "//a[img]" -v "@href" -n 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_members_of_the_United_States_House_of_Representatives'
```

will get you these `href`s.

Now, the URL that is retrieved is not directly the image you want to download; instead it's another HTML page that contains links to the images you want. I've selected the image in these pages with the following xpath:

```
//div[@class='fullImageLink']/a
```

that is, the `a` nodes inside a `div` node with `class="fullImageLink"`. This seems ok, heuristically.

Then, this should do:

```
#!/bin/bash

base="http://en.wikipedia.org"

get_image() {
   local url=$base$1
   printf "*** %s: " "$url"
   IFS= read -r imglink < <(xmlstarlet sel --net --html -t -m "//div[@class='fullImageLink']/a" -v "@href" -n "$url")
   if [[ -z $imglink ]]; then
      echo " ERROR ***"
      return 1
   fi
   imglink="http:$imglink"
   echo " Downloading"
   wget -q "$imglink" &
}

while IFS= read -r url; do
   [[ $url = /wiki/File:* ]] || continue
   get_image "$url"
done < <(
   xmlstarlet sel --net --html -t -m "//a[img]" -v "@href" -n "$base/wiki/Current_members_of_the_United_States_House_of_Representatives"
)
```

You'll get a little bit more than what you want, but it's a good basis `:)`.

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work. It does what I could do previously. It downloads the images directly from the page without waiting for the redirect. I want it to go to a link, get redirected to a link, and then download that link

Comment: @user3702835 What? I don't understand your requirement.

Comment: See, if I were to go to that Wikipedia page and just download it, I would get all the thumbnails, which is what your script does. I want the full-resolution images, which can only be gotten by first clicking on an image thumbnail, getting redirected to the full size image, and then downloading it.

Comment: Great, that works perfectly! A suggestion for other readers: `xmlstartlet` doesn't work for Mac, it's just `xml`. Also, the script needs permission before it can be run - `chmod u+rwx file.sh`